# How to hide alert in react/css

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

Can't seem to get the alert to disappear in 2 seconds. The error message prop pulls from the state and it's generating correctly. Also other implementations are welcome, doesn't have to be using this method. Let me know if more information is needed. Thanks!

In mystyle.module.css file:

```
#hideMe {
    -moz-animation: cssAnimation 0s ease-in 2s forwards;
    /* Firefox */
    -webkit-animation: cssAnimation 0s ease-in 2s forwards;
    /* Safari and Chrome */
    -o-animation: cssAnimation 0s ease-in 2s forwards;
    /* Opera */
    animation: cssAnimation 0s ease-in 2s forwards;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
```

In React file:

```
import hideMe from './mystyle.module.css';
.
.
.
  render() {
    return (
      <div className={s.root}>
        <Row>
          <Col md={12} sm={12} xs={12}>
                {this.props.errorMessage && (
                  <Alert type={hideMe.hideMe} size="sm" color="danger">
                    {this.props.errorMessage}
                  </Alert>
                )}
                {this.props.successMessage && (
                  <Alert id="hideMe" size="sm" color="success">
                    {this.props.successMessage}
                  </Alert>
                )}
            <Widget>
                <FormGroup>
                  <Label for="input-userlogin">User Login</Label>
                  {!this.state.changingLogin ? <Input
                    id="input-userlogin"
                    type="text"
                    placeholder="User Login"
                    value={this.state.userLogin}
                    onChange={this.changeUserLogin}
                  /> : <div><h6>{this.state.userLogin}</h6></div> }
                </FormGroup>
                <div className="d-flex justify-content-end">
                  <ButtonGroup>
                    <Link to="/app/users"><Button color="default">Cancel</Button></Link>
                    {this.props.selectedUser ? 
                      <Button color="danger" onClick={this.doUpdateCreateLogin}>
                        {this.props.isCreated ? 'Updating...' : 'Update'}
                      </Button> :
                      <Button color="danger" type="submit">
                        {this.props.isCreating ? 'Creating...' : 'Create'}
                      </Button>}
                  </ButtonGroup>
                </div>
            </Widget>
          </Col>
        </Row>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    selectedUser: state.users.selectedUser,
    errorMessage: state.users.message,
    isFetching: state.users.isFetching,
  };
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An alternative, very simple implementation is to just work with a state that determines the visibility of the component and changing its value with a timeout in a [useEffect](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) hook (or the `componentDidMount` method for class components).

```js
const { useState, useEffect } = React;

const Alert = () => {
  const [show, setShow] = useState(true);
  useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      setShow(false);
    }, 3000);
  }, []);

  return show && <div>I will be hidden after 3s</div>;
};
const App = () => {
  return <Alert />;
};

// Render it
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```